# How to display directory data in thumbnail in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Right now i am displaying data in simple table row format, but i want to show data in thumbnail format, so user can see what is that without opening it or downloading it.

my current jsp page for to display directory data is following :

```
File folder = new File("d:\\Reports");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
                {
                    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())
                    {
                        if(listOfFiles[i].getName().equals(file_name))
                        {
                            String StrBgEven = "#C6C6C6", strBgOdd = "#CECECE";

                            String [] color={"#C6C6C6","#CECECE"};


                            %>

                                <tr height="28px"  id="table_row"    bgcolor="<%=color[row_counter]%>">
                                  <td width="7%"><div align="center"><%= id=id+1 %></div></td>
                                  <td width="39%"><%=listOfFiles[i].getName() %></td>
                                  <td width="12%"><%= file_type  %></td>
                                  <td width="14%"><%= file_size/1000 %> KB</td>
                                  <td width="14%"><div align="center"><a href="Deletefile?path=d:\Reports\&filename=<%=listOfFiles[i].getName()%>">Delete</a></div></td>
                                  <td width="14%"><div align="center"><a href="Savefile?path=d:\Reports\&filename=<%=listOfFiles[i].getName()%>">Download</a> </div></td>
                                </tr>                             
                            <%
                            row_counter = 1 - row_counter;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

---

> is there anyone who have it's solution ??

---

Comment: You want a thumbnail that shows the preview of the file contents? Is that what you're looking for? If yes, then there is no portable way of doing it.

Comment: @ Arjun Rao, yes exactly i want the preview of stored content on page. Is there not any single way to perform such task ?

Comment: There might be. However the probability of there being a Java API for it is pretty low. You might find programs in other languages which you might have to call to generate the thumbnail, have it stored on the server which hosts your JSP and then have that thumbnail served.

Comment: What is the audience of the code? you have scriptlets in your JSP which you shouldnt be using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use div and make it's css as per your need and make all thing dynamic.
Try to use css but external not internal or embedded.
and display each one as separate and just use one inside scriplet it will work for each one result same...